# using socket.io with PHP server

Tags: php, sockets, socket.io, comet

I am implementing socket.io in an Open Source PHP application. But socket.io is not work directly on PHP server.

In their document they have proposed a PHP solution, and its look fine. but main problem is that their propesed solution: https://github.com/rase-/socket.io-php-emitter need two PHP extensions to be installed **msgpack-php** and **phpredis**. And this extension are generally not installed in PHP server.

As my application is Open Source and most of our user will use it on shared hosting, where they are not allowed to install any PHP extensions.

**My question is**

Is there any PHP client library for **msgpack-php** and **phpredis** with easy integartion.

**OR**

Is there any PHP `REAL-TIME ENGINE` for pusing content to client side ?

Thanks for being helpful.

Comment: Do you need socket.io to work on a webpage that is a php file?

Comment: Perhaps [elephant.io](http://elephant.io) will work for you?